# AndroidManifest.xml - A row is auto-changing when I build the project

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, compiler-errors, build-process

I have the class: "Page1", then I add the following to my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.example.giacomob.myapplication.Page1"
   android:label="@string/textView2" >
</activity>
```

But when I build the project, this row changed to:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.example.giacomob.myapplication.textView2"
   android:label="@string/textView2" >
</activity>
```

Why?

The same thing happens if I delete the rows: when I rebuild the project, the rows reappear! Please, help me.

Comment: make sure you are not editing the android manifest inside the bin folder!

Comment: Posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are editing the wrong Manifest file in the /bin Folder ;)

I tried it out and thats what happens if you edit the wrong file...